# Can't Upload Files more than 100M Apache2 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2

I am using php7.1 locally and trying to upload 7 files of more than 100mbs. When it reaches to 50% upload it automatically refresh the page and nothing is uploaded.

On my local path:

```
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini
```

I have following configuration:

```
max_input_time = 300
max_execution_time = 300
post_max_size = 140M
upload_max_filesize = 140M
memory_limit = 1024M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Also i have tried to increase the size of post_max_size and upload_max_filesize more than 140mbs but no success . can anybody help me out from this?

Comment: And this? `max_file_uploads = 20` increase to `400` If one file for web has max 100kb x 20 files.......